# Split and Join strings in C Language

Tags: c

I learnt C in uni but haven't used it for quite a few years. Recently I started working on a tool which uses C as the programming language. Now I'm stuck with some really basic functions. Among them are how to split and join strings using a delimiter? (I miss Python so much, even Java or C#!)

Below is the function I created to split a string, but it does not seem to work properly. Also, even this function works, the delimiter can only be a single character. How can I use a string as a delimiter?

Can someone please provide some help?

Ideally, I would like to have 2 functions:

```
//  Split a string into a string array
char** fSplitStr(char *str, const char *delimiter);

//  Join the elements of a string array to a single string
char* fJoinStr(char **str, const char *delimiter);
```

Thank you,

Allen

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char** fSplitStr(char *str, const char *delimiters)
{
    char * token; 
    char **tokenArray;
    int count=0;
    token = (char *)strtok(str, delimiters); // Get the first token
    tokenArray = (char**)malloc(1 * sizeof(char*));

    if (!token) {       
        return tokenArray;  
} 

    while (token != NULL ) { // While valid tokens are returned     
        tokenArray[count] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(token));
        tokenArray[count] = token;
        printf ("%s", tokenArray[count]);    
        count++;
        tokenArray = (char **)realloc(tokenArray, sizeof(char *) * count);      
        token = (char *)strtok(NULL, delimiters); // Get the next token     
} 
    return tokenArray;
}

int main (void)
{
    char str[] = "Split_The_String";
    char ** splitArray = fSplitStr(str,"_");
    printf ("%s", splitArray[0]);
    printf ("%s", splitArray[1]);
    printf ("%s", splitArray[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answers: (Thanks to Moshbear, Joachim and sarnold):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char** fStrSplit(char *str, const char *delimiters)
{
    char * token; 
    char **tokenArray;
    int count=0;
    token = (char *)strtok(str, delimiters); // Get the first token
    tokenArray = (char**)malloc(1 * sizeof(char*));
    tokenArray[0] = NULL;
    if (!token) {       
        return tokenArray;  
    } 
    while (token != NULL) { // While valid tokens are returned
        tokenArray[count] = (char*)strdup(token);
        //printf ("%s", tokenArray[count]);
        count++;
        tokenArray = (char **)realloc(tokenArray, sizeof(char *) * (count + 1));
        token = (char *)strtok(NULL, delimiters); // Get the next token
    }
    tokenArray[count] = NULL;  /* Terminate the array */
    return tokenArray;
}

char* fStrJoin(char **str, const char *delimiters)
{
    char *joinedStr;
    int i = 1;
    joinedStr = realloc(NULL, strlen(str[0])+1);
    strcpy(joinedStr, str[0]);
    if (str[0] == NULL){
        return joinedStr;
    }
    while (str[i] !=NULL){
        joinedStr = (char*)realloc(joinedStr, strlen(joinedStr) + strlen(str[i]) + strlen(delimiters) + 1);
        strcat(joinedStr, delimiters);
        strcat(joinedStr, str[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return joinedStr;
}


int main (void)
{
    char str[] = "Split_The_String";
    char ** splitArray = (char **)fStrSplit(str,"_");
    char * joinedStr;
    int i=0;
    while (splitArray[i]!=NULL) {
        printf ("%s", splitArray[i]);
        i++;
    }
    joinedStr = fStrJoin(splitArray, "-");
    printf ("%s", joinedStr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `strpbrk` instead of `strtok`, because `strtok` suffers from two weaknesses:

- it's not re-entrant (i.e. thread-safe)
- it modifies the string

For joining, use `strncat` for joining, and `realloc` for resizing.
The order of operations is very important.

Before doing the `realloc;strncat` loop, set the 0th element of the target string to `'\0'` so that `strncat` won't cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks Moshbear. I will try strpbrk function. However, the current problem in the code is it can only print the first element. An error is encountered while the "printf ("%s", splitArray[1]);" line is executed. Any ideas? I feel there is something wrong with this line - "tokenArray = (char **)realloc(tokenArray, sizeof(char *) * count);" but just don't know exactly why.

Comment: You reallocate `sizeof(char *) * (count + 1)`. Also, when inputting into strpbrk, increment the input string pointer after calculating the token length so that you don't have an infinite loop. The reason for this being that `strpbrk` behaves like C++'s `std::find_first_of`, so you have to increment until the pointer points to the first character not in the delimiter set.

Comment: Thanks Moshbear. After changing that line to "sizeof(char *) * (count + 1)", it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

For starters, don't use `sizeof` to get the length of a string. `strlen` is the function to use. In this case `strdup` is better.

And you don't actually copy the string returned by `strtok`, you copy the pointer. Change you loop to this:

```
while (token != NULL) { // While valid tokens are returned
    tokenArray[count] = strdup(token);
    printf ("%s", tokenArray[count]);
    count++;
    tokenArray = (char **)realloc(tokenArray, sizeof(char *) * count);
    token = (char *)strtok(NULL, delimiters); // Get the next token
}
tokenArray[count] = NULL;  /* Terminate the array */
```

Also, don't forget to free the entries in the array, and the array itself when you're done with it.

**Edit** At the beginning of `fSplitStr`, wait with allocating the `tokenArray` until after you check that `token` is not `NULL`, and if `token` is `NULL` why not return `NULL`?

Comment: Thanks a lot Joachim. I tried your code but got the same error. An unhandled exception is encountered while the "printf ("%s", splitArray[1]);" line is executed. However, the first element can be printed correctly. Also, all the elements can be printed inside the loop by the "printf ("%s", tokenArray[count]);" statement.

Comment: @Allen Your code works for me, as given in your question. No exceptions or crashes.

Comment: thanks for your help. It now works after I made the change suggested by Moshbear. Also I will make the change to return'NULL' if the first token is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the *best* solution for you, but I do have a few notes:

```
token = (char *)strtok(str, delimiters); // Get the first token
tokenArray = (char**)malloc(1 * sizeof(char*));

if (!token) {       
    return tokenArray;  
}
```

At this point, if you weren't able to find any tokens in the string, you return a pointer to an "array" that is large enough to hold a single character pointer. It is un-initialized, so it would not be a good idea to *use* the contents of this array in any way. C almost never initializes memory to `0x00` for you. (`calloc(3)` would do that for you, but since you need to overwrite every element anyway, it doesn't seem worth switching to `calloc(3)`.)

Also, the `(char **)` case before the `malloc(3)` call indicates to me that you've probably forgotten the `#include <stdlib.h>` that would properly prototype `malloc(3)`. (The cast was necessary before about 1989.)

Do note that your `while() { }` loop is setting *pointers* to the *parts* of the original input string to your `tokenArray` elements. (This is one of the *cons* that moshbear mentioned in his answer -- though it isn't always a weakness.) If you change `tokenArray[1][1]='H'`, then your original input string *also* changes. (In addition to having each of the delimiter characters replaced with an ASCII `NUL` character.)

Comment: thanks for your comments and I will make the change as you advised. The reason I put the cast (char **) is the code won't work within that tool (HP Loadrunner). I will investigate if adding  #include <stdlib.h> can fix the problem.