# How do you reverse the word order in a sentence?

Tags: c, char, reverse, c-strings, function-definition

The task was to reverse the order of words in the sentence
I was able to reverse the order of the words, but the problem is that the order of the letters in the word also changes

For example: cats and dogs

The miracle in my plan:tac dna sgod

The desired output: dogs and cats

How can I fix the code to work correctly?

this is my code:

```
void revSent(char str[]) {
    int i;
    int n = strlen(str);
    char letter;

    for (i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
        letter = str[i];
        str[i] = str[strlen(str) - i - 1];

        str[strlen(str) - i - 1]=letter ;
    
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118269/split-and-join-strings-in-c-language

Comment: Note that you can reverse the whole string and then reverse each word.

Answer (score 0):

You could split your sentence with the whitespace and then you can reorder the resulting array in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to reverse the whole string and then to reverse each word in the string separately.

To extract words in a string you can use standard string functions `strspn` and `strcspn`.

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse_n( char *s, size_t n )
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n - i - 1];
        s[n - i - 1] = c;
    }
}

char *revSent( char *s )
{
    const char *blank = " \t";

    reverse_n( s, strlen( s ) );

    for (char *p = s; *p; )
    {
        p += strspn( p, blank );

        if (*p)
        {
            size_t n = strcspn( p, blank );
            reverse_n( p, n );
            p += n;
        }
    }

    return s;
}

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = "cats and dogs";

    puts( s );
    puts( revSent( s ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
cats and dogs
dogs and cats
```